# SQL Server Temp Table with a High Sort

Tags: sql-server, temp-tables

I don't seen to understand why I would be getting an `Sort Cost` on an `temp table` that I included an non-clustered.

> Do I need to build the Statistics after the creating the index?

```
CREATE TABLE #TempGuidelineLog
(
[ID] int identity(1,1) NOT NULL,
[CustomerId] int,[LogDate] DateTime,
CONSTRAINT [PK_#TempTable'] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    ([ID] ASC) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF
     ,STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF
     ,IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF
     ,ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON
     ,ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT #TempGuidelineLog ([CustomerId], [LogDate]) 
SELECT g.CustomerId, g.LogDate FROM vwGuidelineLog  g
where g.LogDate >= '2017-10-01' and g.LogDate < dateadd(day, 1, '2018-09-30')

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_temp1Customer ON #TempGuidelineLog (CustomerId)
INCLUDE ([LogDate])

    select
    g.*,
    a.StateId, 
    a.CountryId
    into #TempCustomerAddress
    from #TempGuidelineLog g
    JOIN [vwCustomerAddress] a ON a.CustomerId = g.CustomerId
```

[image: Temp Table Sort at 77%]

Comment: Is there a clustered index? Why `*` if there are two columns? Does the plan start with scan of `#`?

Comment: @IvanStarostin There is no clustered index on the temp table

Comment: Why did you start with nonclustered? Make this one clustered. If CustomerID is unique - make it primary key.

Comment: @IvanStarostin I tried both nonclustered and clustered updated the sql but I am still getting high sort 79% and 24 seconds to completed

Comment: paste the whole plan here https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJpB_wCcQ

Comment: 79% - it's not the select query, it's the index build. Yes, sorting of 5M+ rows takes some time. But now a wonderful merge join is possible. If those 5M rows are originally in different order - how would they become sorted without sort operation? Maybe it will be a bit faster if you create temp table with the index in first place and then perform insert into it.

Comment: I updated the SQL but it is not much faster https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SyNhsw09m

Comment: That's it. Left options to improve: upgrade hardware or process data by smaller batches (which will probably take more time in total). PS I don't understand the second insert in the plan. I don't see it in the shown code.

Comment: Perhaps you should add an index on the vwGuidelineLog view from which you are pulling the data that populates your temp table with an already created index in place.

Comment: Why did you invent the ID column and put primary key/clustered index on it? Still want more sorting?

Comment: I was thinking that would stop SQL from having to sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chances to improve

- create temp table first
- put a clustered index on it instead of dancing with a heap
- if customerid is unique make this index PK
- try to process these data in batches, not all at once

code:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempGuidelineLog
(
  [CustomerId] int NOT NULL,
  [LogDate] DateTime NOT NULL
)
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX ix_temp1Customer ON #TempGuidelineLog (CustomerId)

INSERT #TempGuidelineLog ([CustomerId], [LogDate]) 
SELECT g.CustomerId, g.LogDate FROM vwGuidelineLog  g
where g.LogDate >= '2017-10-01' and g.LogDate < dateadd(day, 1, '2018-09-30')
```

There is no way to avoid sorting if it is **needed**. Seeking unsorted date leads to... implicit sorting or loop+scan. And sorting 5M+ rows cannot have zero cost.

Note, the last plan you've pasted contains additional insert of the same data. I think it's a typo, so removing it will avoid unnecessary workload.